# Category wise access to user

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

We are having a requirement according to which the access on the `Web contents` is to be given on the basis of categories.

Example: (i.e): if a role `Report` is being given to a `user`, then the user should be able to view only those web contents which are associated with the Report category.

How can this be achieved with `liferay` `6.2`?

Answer (score 0):

The UI will have nothing for you, as this is not the typical way that Liferay handles permissions. There are several options that you can choose from:

First of all you should check *why* this requirement exists: Quite often I'm seeing permissions being used where "relevance" is actually the way to go: Check if users *absolutely must not see* content from other categories, or if it would just be irrelevant for them. Don't use permissions to solve "relevance" problems.

My favored solution would be that you determine this is the case. If it isn't here are some other options that you have:

Liferay's permissions work best (and best maintainable) if you separate content with different permissions into different sites. This way you can use the easiest bulk permissions. You can create all the different content in different sites and still show them on other sites - e.g. through AssetPublisher or custom portlets.

You can also create a Hook that automatically sets the required permissions whenever an article is saved. Liferay's API is available and can be overridden with the required operation. In fact, you won't override, but rather add to the standard behaviour.